# Golang - http.Redirect fails to redirect in a handler than handles post data

Tags: http, redirect, go

I was thinking of doing the following for the authentication.

(1) Client visits home,say http://localhost:3000
The client is shown a login form with username, password, gamecode.

(2) When the client submits this form, I use javascript to post the data to 
http://localhost:3000/login that accepts POST requests. In my golang file the relevant route is defined as:

```
rtr := mux.NewRouter()
rtr.HandleFunc("/login", loginHandler).Methods("POST")
```

(3) Now I want to check if the three, username, password and the gamecode are valid. I start with the gamecode, and I have no difficulty reading the value submitted and checking in against the list of valid gamecodes in the database. Now, if the gamecode is invalid, I want to redirect the user to another route. I am failing to do so. These are the relevant lines:

```
// I check if gamecode is valid. If it is invalid, gameCodeExists = 0
if gameCodeExists == 0 {
    // this message prints on the server as expected for an invalid code
    fmt.Println("gamecode invalid...")

    // this redirect never occurs
    http.Redirect(w, req, "/loginfail", 302)
    return
} else {
    fmt.Println("Valid code")
}
```

Can someone please help me with what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: is there anything else in the handler writing to `w`?

Comment: There is nothing else writing to the handler. That was another question I had. Can I not write something before redirecting? Also, I noticed that if I submit the form using `action=url` then redirect works. However, if I submit it using Ajax post then it does not. Is there a way to use Redirect when the request comes from Ajax call? Thanks.

Comment: If an Ajax request receive a redirection it will not redirect the current page to the new one. The way to do it, here, it's to catch the http request in your javascript response and look at the http code sent (301 or 3xx about redirecting) then redirect to the url